# Binding event listeners function, do I need to call the function later?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using an api which includes these event listeners for changing the display of a div from hidden to visible.

```
function bindEventListeners() {
    /* cart close button listener */
    $('.cart .btn--close').on('click', closeCart);

    /* click away listener to close cart */
    $(document).on('click', function(evt) {
      if((!$(evt.target).closest('.cart').length) && (!$(evt.target).closest('.js-prevent-cart-listener').length)) {
        closeCart();
      }
    });
};
```

These listeners aren't working, the click away listener doesn't work and neither does the close button one. In the support docs they're just given like this but does the function bindEventListeners need to be called somewhere for them to be working or how should they listen?

Comment: In order to execute the code in a function, yes, the function has to be invoked somewhere, after the elements it refers exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to call `bindEventListeners()` after `.cart .btn--close` exists. If that element exists statically on the page you should call it in the `$(document).ready()` handler like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    bindEventListeners();
})
```

Or if `.cart .btn--close` is created dynamically say through an ajax call then the `bindEventListeners()` should be done after it is loaded into the DOM.

Comment: Ah thank you very much! I have set it to call inside the $(document).ready() handler :)